# In Ruby, using the any method to return a value

Tags: ruby

I use the any? method to check for something within an array, e.g. (simplified example, actual condition more complex)

```
%w{ant bear cat}.any? {|word| word == 'cat'}
```

it will return true. But what if I want the actual match to return? e.g. "cat" for above? I thought of using something like this:

```
%w{ant bear cat}.any? {|word| (@x=word) == 'cat'}
```

But it does not look nice.

Comment: If you insist on using `any?` you could write `%w{ant bear cat}.any? {|word| (@x=word) == 'cat'} && 'cat'`, which returns `false` or `'cat'`.

Answer (score 3):

In such case use `select` to return the elements equal to 'cat' or `find` to return the first element equal to 'cat':

```
p %w{ant bear cat}.find {|word| word == 'cat'}
# => "cat"

p %w{ant bear cat}.select {|word| word == 'cat'}
# => ["cat"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%w{ant bear cat}.find {|word| word == 'cat'}
# => "cat"
```